# MS Access Date not working in VBA SQL query

Tags: ms-access, vba

There is a table in MS Access having 3 columns:

1. ID (Primary key)
2. Date (Date/Time)
3. Train no (short text)

I have designed a form where date can be selected from a combo box and according to the date selected, respective trains should be displayed.

Problem is, the query works fine on dates above 10 (like 11/1/2015) but below 10 (like 9/1/2015) it gives error : "No current record" . The record is there in the table but it doesn't display.

The query is : `SELECT DISTINCT [Train No] FROM Issue WHERE [Date] = #" & dt & "#"`

dt is the date selected from the combo box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim DateSelected As Date
Dim DateString   As String

DateSelected = DateValue(Me!YourComboBox.Value)
DateString = Format(DateSelected, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")

SELECT DISTINCT [Train No] FROM Issue WHERE [Date] = #" & DateString & "#"
```

Comment: Thanks :) It worked. Can u please explain why it takes only this format?

Comment: In SQL, string expressions for date values must be formatted as yyyy-mm-dd or mm-dd-yyyy (or slashes as separator). As yyyy-mm-dd also is the only reliable format for ADO, stick to the ISO format yyyy-mm-ss as a general rule.

Comment: But why then it was working for dates above 10 (like 11/1/2015) ? Does it parse differently for those formats?

Comment: I guess that if you `Debug.Print` your old SQL string, that would show why.

Comment: There is just a change of date format. Thanks for your time.